# Middleware lanza un error

Tags: nextjs, middleware

Tengo un middleware en mi app de next para que convierta todas las urls (excepto las rutas de la api) a minúsculas.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const Middleware = (req) => {
  const {
    pathname,
    search,
    origin
  } = req.nextUrl;
  if (pathname.startsWith('/api') || pathname === pathname.toLowerCase())
    return NextResponse.next();

  return NextResponse.redirect(
    `${origin + pathname.toLowerCase() + search}`
  );
};

export default Middleware;
```

Funciona para lo que yo espero, pero el problema es que en todas las páginas de mi aplicación recibo un error en consola:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invariant: attempted to hard navigate to the same URL

Este error no parece afectar a mi aplicación pero quisiera saber por qué está ahí y cómo eliminarlo.  Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema ocurre debido a un error de Violación de Invariación (`Invariant Violation`) que sucede al intentar navegar directamente a la misma URL después de que el usuario ya haya navegado allí.

Para resolver este problema, puedes crear un objeto de configuración y establecer la propiedad matcher, como un arreglo de expresiones regulares que coincidan con todas las rutas de solicitud excepto las que comienzan con:

- api (rutas de API)
- _next/static (archivos estáticos)
- _next/image (archivos de imágenes)
- favicon.ico (favicon de la app)

Para implementar esta solución, agrega el siguiente código a tu proyecto:

```
export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
  ],
}
```

Snippet de codigo de la [documentación de Next.js][1].
El código final se verá así:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all request paths except for the ones starting with:
     * - api (API routes)
     * - _next/static (static files)
     * - _next/image (image optimization files)
     * - favicon.ico (favicon file)
     */
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
    '/',
  ],
};

const Middleware = (req) => {
  const {
    pathname,
    search,
    origin
  } = req.nextUrl;
  if (pathname === pathname.toLowerCase())
    return NextResponse.next();

  return NextResponse.redirect(
    `${origin + pathname.toLowerCase() + search}`
  );
};

export default Middleware;
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, es tu primera participación en el sitio,  te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.